# Web Crawler Node.JS don't work on this website

Tags: node.js, web-crawler

I want to use web crawler for get images URL from this site: https://style.lookli.st/

I test my code to other site and works. I don't get why I can't receive URL from images.

Here is Node.JS implementation:

```js
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var fs = require('fs');

request("https://style.lookli.st", function(error, response, body) {
  if(error) {
    console.log("Error: " + error);
  }
  console.log("Status code: " + response.statusCode);

  var $ = cheerio.load(body);

    $('.img-look').each(function( index ) {
    var link = $(this).attr('src');
    fs.appendFileSync('URL.txt', link + '\r\n');
  });

});
```

Comment: https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio/blob/master/Readme.md#cheerio-is-not-a-web-browser

Comment: I use cheerio. Check the second line of code.